# SQL Function with variable parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, concatenation

as title above, I need to make a function in SQL using variable parameters
It serves primarily to concat fields into 1 field. So for example:

```
MyConcat(1, 'xxx', 23456, 'yyyy') will result '1-xxx-23456-yyyy'
```

or

```
MyConcat('aaa', 123, 888) will result 'aaa-123-888'
```

it supposed to be very easy on another language, but how to define in SQL?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `SELECT column1 + '-' + column2`...

Comment: It can be easily done on Select query? Still you want function?

Comment: you can't do that.. you have to define as convert(col1 as varchar) + '-' + convert(col2 as varchar) + '-' + convert(col3 as varchar) + '-' .... And you have to do it on every query. Yes I can do it on select query, but to make few inner join based on that is pretty ugly on code

Comment: @Magician all the queries have same data type? How much columns needs to be concatenated?

Comment: no.. multiple data types, decimals, varchar, numeric. Columns needed are variable, depending on how many fields being used to identify data. Some using 4, some 3, some 2. 4 is the most i've found, and there are still some more tables that I haven't checked yet. So perhaps there are more

Comment: Then its not possible to create a common function for all. There is no base 'object' type available in SQL. So you have to convert the DataType before passing to function as the above select statement.

Comment: can't you just put varchar as parameter type and SQL will convert everything to varchar? Results are always varchar no matter what the other column types are

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72106/discussion-between-selva-ts-and-magician).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirements, you can create your customized `CLR` function like this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91e6taax(v=VS.90).aspx